# Using recursion in DFS to solve a logic game using C?

Tags: c, search, recursion, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I have the following problem: The goal of this game is to remove all pegs but one from the board. The perfect game leaves only one peg in the center position (the black one). Basically, pegs are removed by jumping over each peg with another peg. I can only jump over a peg if there is an empty space on the other side of it and I am right before it.

[image: general positioning of the pegs]

I am trying to understand the following recursive function that tries to solve the problem using Depth First Search. Although I am kind of familiar with how the problem works in normal conditions, meaning when I have pegs to remove. I can't grasp very well the recursive step when I end up in situations where there is no more possibility to eliminate the pegs where in the next steps I was obliged to come up with the old eliminated peg (backtrack) so that I will find another path to the solution. This seems to consume a lot of execution time.

The general procedure of the function is to:

1. Iterate over the board using a nested for loop.
2. Find the peg to move if the following conditions are true:
3. There is a direct adjacent one to it either to the left right up or down.
4. There is a free place to move to after removing the peg to be removed.
5. If all those conditions are true we change the states of the pegs
6. If there is no more the possibility to move pegs, restore the previous board configuration and find another path.

Here are the preprocessor directives:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 11
/****** Accepted or unaccepted solution ******/
#define YES 1
#define NO 0

/****** Representation of the board ******/
/* 0 - the position is free: no peg is in the position
   1 - a peg is in the postion
   2 - an obstacle is in the position (not part of the board) */  

#define OCCUPIED 1
#define FREE 0
#define WALL 2

/****** Stack size ******/
#define MAXST 5000

typedef char boolean;
/****** Directions where to move *****/
enum dir{NORTH,EAST,SOUTH,WEST};
/****** Directions horizentally ******/
int dx[]={0, 1,0,-1};
/****** Directions Vertically ******/
int dy[]={-1,0,1, 0};

/****** Board Representation ******/
char b[N][N]={
{2, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 2},

{2, 2,2,2,1,0,0,2,2,2, 2},
{2, 2,2,2,0,0,1,2,2,2, 2},
{2, 2,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,2, 2},
{2, 0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1, 2},
{2, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 2},
{2, 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0, 2},
{2, 2,2,2,1,0,0,2,2,2, 2},
{2, 2,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,2, 2},
{2, 2,2,2,1,0,0,2,2,2, 2},

{2, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 2}
};
```

Here is the function responsible for finding a solution:

```
    /****** move finds the next move to perform in order to advance in the search ******/
    boolean move(int pegs){
    /****** x - the x position of the peg examined on the board
            y - the y position of the peg examined on the board
            xnear - the x position of the adjascent peg to be removed
            ynear - the y position of the adjascent peg to be removed
            xnew - the new x position of the peg that expelled the removed previous peg
            ynew - the new x position of the peg that expelled the removed previous peg ****/
    int x,y,xnear,ynear,xnew,ynew;

    enum dir d;

    /* Base case 1: solution = one peg left on the whole board */

    /* if(pegs==1){
        return(YES);
    } */

    /* Base case 2: solution = one peg at the center of the board (5,5) */
        if(pegs==1) {
            if (b[5][5]==OCCUPIED)
                return(YES);
            else return(NO);
        }
        /*Scanning the board from top to bottom, left to right*/
        for(x=0;x<N;x++)
            for(y=0;y<N;y++)
            /* In order for the move to occur you need to 1. have a peg in a position */
                if(b[y][x] == OCCUPIED){
                    /**************/
                    /* Finding adjascent pegs to remove from the board */ 
                    for(d=NORTH;d<=WEST;d++){
                        xnear=x+dx[d];
                        ynear=y+dy[d];
                        /*****************/
                        /* 2. Have another peg adjascent to the peg making the move */
                        if(b[ynear][xnear]== OCCUPIED){
                            xnew=xnear+dx[d];
                            ynew=ynear+dy[d];
                            /****************/
                            /* 3. Have the position where the peg will be moving empty */
                            if(b[ynew][xnew]==FREE){
                                b[y][x]=FREE; /* do move */
                                b[ynear][xnear]=FREE;   
                                b[ynew][xnew]=OCCUPIED;
                                pegs--;
                                print_board(b);
                                push(b,x,y,d); // Pushing the action to a stack
                                if(move(pegs)){
                                    return(YES);
                                }

                                b[y][x]=OCCUPIED; /* undo move */
                                b[ynear][xnear]=OCCUPIED;
                                b[ynew][xnew]=FREE;

                                pegs++;
                                pop(); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            return(NO);
        }
```

My questions would be:

1. How does the recursive part of the `boolean move(int pegs)` function work in the code, and how can it keep track of the already expanded cases that have led to a dead end?
   My guess would be in the `boolean move(int pegs)` function and precisely:

   ```
           if(move(pegs)){
                return(YES);
           }
           b[y][x]=OCCUPIED; /* undo move */
           b[ynear][xnear]=OCCUPIED;
           b[ynew][xnew]=FREE;
           print_board(b);
           pegs++;
           pop();
   ```
2. Is it normal that the execution is taking too long to find a solution (many hours and did not find a solution yet)? Is there a way to improve the execution time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a lot of states that will be generated. 
Initially, there are four possible moves. Each of these moves leads to several possible moves and so on. When you use backtracking, you have to actually store these state spaces.

You can think of this search as a tree where the root is the initial state. 
(So, the initial state generates four children... and so on!)

### When using backtracking

Whenever a dead end is reached, there should be a boolean function which finds out if a move is possible and if there aren't any moves possible, we go to the parent from which the dead end was reached and try out the parent's other children.

We keep doing the above procedure until we reach a solution.